# Match Data In Two Files Then Email Each Person

Tags: jenkins, vbscript

For simplicity, file1.txt is a log file for which I extract logonIds into an array. File2.txt contains rows of logonID,emailAddress,other,needless,data

I need to take all of the logonIDs read into my array from file1 and extract their email addresses from file2. Once I have this information, I can then send each person in file1 an email. Can't just use file2.txt because it contains users who should not receive an email.

I wrote vbscript that extracts logonIDs from file1.txt into array and pulls logonID and email from file2.txt

```
inFile1 = "C:\Scripts\testvbs\wscreatestatus.txt"
inFile2 = "C:\Scripts\testvbs\WSBatchCreateBuildsList.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objInFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile1, ForReading)
Set objInFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile2, ForReading)

'Creates Array of all DomainIDs for successful deployments
Do Until objInFile1.AtEndOfStream 
    strNextLine = objInFile1.Readline
    arrLogons = Split(strNextLine , vbTab)
        If arrLogons(0) = "DEPLOYSUCCESS" Then
             arrUserIDList = arrUserIDList & arrLogons(5) & vbCrLf
        End If  
Loop

Do Until objInFile2.AtEndOfStream 
    strNextLine = objInFile2.Readline
    arrAddressList = Split(strNextLine , ",")
    arrMailList = arrMailList & arrAddressList(0) & vbTab & arrAddressList(1) & vbCrLf

Loop
```

What I need to do next is take my list of user IDs "arrUserIDList", and extract their email address from arrMailList.  With this information I can send each user in file1.txt (wscreatestatus.txt) an email.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you construct your `arrMailList`, I presume you want the selected LogonID's and corresponding email addresses output to a new Tab delimited text file.

If that is the case, I recommend using ArrayList objects to store the values in. ArrayLists have an easy to use `Add` method and for testing if an item is in an ArrayList, there is the `Contains` method.

In Code:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim inFile1, inFile2, outFile, objFSO, objInFile, objOutFile
Dim strNextLine, fields, arrUserIDList, arrMailList

inFile1 = "C:\Scripts\testvbs\wscreatestatus.txt"
inFile2 = "C:\Scripts\testvbs\WSBatchCreateBuildsList.txt"
outFile = "C:\Scripts\testvbs\WSEmailDeploySuccess.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile1, ForReading)

'Create an ArrayList of all DomainIDs for successful deployments
Set arrUserIDList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )

Do Until objInFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objInFile.Readline
    fields = Split(strNextLine , vbTab)
    If fields(0) = "DEPLOYSUCCESS" Then
         arrUserIDList.Add fields(5)
    End If
Loop

'close the first input file
objInFile.Close

'Now read the second file and read the logonID's from it
Set objInFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile2, ForReading)

'Create an ArrayList of all LogonID's, a TAB character and the EmailAddress
Set arrMailList = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )

Do Until objInFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objInFile.Readline
    fields = Split(strNextLine , ",")
    If arrUserIDList.Contains(fields(0)) Then
        ' store the values in arrMailList as TAB separated values
        arrMailList.Add fields(0) & vbTab & fields(1)
    End If
Loop

'close the file and destroy the object
objInFile.Close
Set objInFile = Nothing

Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outFile, ForWriting, True)
For Each strNextLine In arrMailList
    objOutFile.WriteLine(strNextLine)
Next

'close the file and destroy the object
objOutFile.Close
Set objOutFile = Nothing

'clean up the other objects
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set arrUserIDList = Nothing
Set arrMailList = Nothing
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Theo.  I took a different approach and managed to get my script to work, but your solution looks perfect. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem, but I think Theo took a better approach.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim inFile1, inFile2, strNextLine, arrServiceList, arrUserList
Dim arrUserDeployList, strLine, arrList, outFile, strItem1, strItem2

inFile1 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0) 'wscreatestatus.txt file (tab delimited)
inFile2 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1) 'WSBatchCreateBuildsList.txt (comma delimited)
outFile = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2) 'SuccessWSMailList###.txt (for Welcome emails)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objInFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile1, ForReading)
Set objInFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile2, ForReading)
Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, ForWriting, True)

'Extracts Logon ID's for successfull deployments into an Array
'#================================================================
i = 0
Do Until objInFile1.AtEndOfStream 
    ReDim Preserve arrUsers(i)
        strNextLine = objInFile1.Readline
        arrLogons = Split(strNextLine , vbTab)
            If arrLogons(0) = "PENDINGREQUESTS" Then
                arrUsers(i) = arrLogons(5)
                i = i + 1
            End If  
    Loop

'Extracts success deploy email addresses and writes to file
'#================================================================
Do Until objInFile2.AtEndOfStream 
    ReDim Preserve arrMailList(i)
    strNextLine = objInFile2.Readline
        arrAddressList = Split(strNextLine , ",")
        strItem1 = arrAddressList(0)
        strItem2 = arrAddressList(1)
            For Each strArrayEntry In arrUsers
                If strArrayEntry = strItem1 Then 
                     objOutFile.WriteLine strItem1 & "," & strItem2 
                End If
            Next
    i = i + 1
    Loop

objOutFile.Close
objInFile1.Close
objInFile2.Close
```